# Matplotlib Markers as Tick Labels

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, axis-labels

Given the following code, I'd like to replace the y-tick label numbers with stars, the number of which corresponding to each number. For example, the top label should be 10 stars, aligned such that the last star is placed where the 0 in 10 currently resides. They need to be dynamically generated, meaning I want to avoid using plt.xticks(['**********',.....]):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2]
y = [1, 4]
labels = ['Bogs', 'Slogs']
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.xticks(x, labels, rotation='vertical')
plt.margins(0.2)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.show()
```

Here's basically what I'm trying to produce (dynamic numbers of stars per the underlying y-tick label values):

[image: Like this]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing you mean you don't want to use `plt.yticks(['**********',.....])`, i.e. `y`, not `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't actually *write out* the stars, then. When using a programming language, program! :-)

```
y_limit = 5
y_labels = ['*' * i for i in range(y_limit)]
plt.yticks(range(y_limit), y_labels)
```

Comment: Thank-you, Praveen. A follow-up question (which I should have asked in the first place): What If I want the stars to be actual stars as in with marker='*'?

Comment: @DanceParty2 Oh, that's harder. I don't know how. You'll need to make the markers plot outside of the plot area somehow, I guess... You should probably ask a separate question. If you can, include what you mean by `marker='*'` in your expected output figure.